# How to extract an Integral pattern out of a String using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, string-formatting

I am trying to make a mapLoader, which reads in a text file (here is an example) of the file

```
[5,3,3,900,3,89,3,3,3,3,3,430,3,1439,3,65,3,320,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3]
[5,3,3,900,3,89,3,3,3,3,3,430,3,1439,3,65,3,320,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3]
[5,3,3,900,3,89,3,3,3,3,3,430,3,1439,3,65,3,320,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3]
[5,3,3,900,3,89,3,3,3,3,3,430,3,1439,3,65,3,320,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3]
[5,3,3,900,3,89,3,3,3,3,3,430,3,1439,3,65,3,320,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3]
[5,3,3,900,3,89,3,3,3,3,3,430,3,1439,3,65,3,320,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3]
[5,3,3,900,3,89,3,3,3,3,3,430,3,1439,3,65,3,320,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3]
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3]
```

**I load every line into a String[15] so each Bracket is isolated from the rest**

I am creating a game, it's a 2D RPG (so original right?), the numbers above are key integers that tell where to put a tile Image, and what tile Image to use in the 
"mapTile BufferedImage[]"

Each number inside the brackets represent 1 unit on the X axis,

Each Collection of brackets makes up 1 unit on the Y axis.

**My grid size is 24x15**

My problem is I am trying to grab the numbers, and put them into an int[24][15], but as you can tell, it can vary in String length. The most amount of "digits" that can be used in between commas is "4" because I dont have more than 9999 mapTiles lol

**How do I create a Regular Expression that extracts that information?**

Comment: You use the `split` method of the `String` class to split each string on the commas, then iterate through the resulting array using `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: You may also use Scanner.nextInt() to get rid of extra parseInts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data set is too simple to employ regular expressions. You can easily split the lines by `,` commas to parse your coordinates. Also, you probably need an `int[15][24]` here instead of `int[24][15]` if you want to store the coordinates as `int[rows][cols]` given that your grid is `24x15`.

```
int[][] coords = new int[15][24];
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file"));

int row = 0;
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // remove "[ ]" then split by ","
    String[] x = line.substring(1, line.length() - 1).split(",");
    // parse first 24 values only
    int cols = Math.min(x.length, 24);
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        coords[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(x[col]);
    }
    if (++row >= 15) break; // parse first 15 lines only
}

for (int i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < coords[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(coords[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

***Output** :*

```
53390038933333430314393653320333333
3333333333333333332133333
53390038933333430314393653320333333
3333333333333333332133333
53390038933333430314393653320333333
3333333333333333332133333
53390038933333430314393653320333333
3333333333333333332133333
53390038933333430314393653320333333
3333333333333333332133333
53390038933333430314393653320333333
3333333333333333332133333
53390038933333430314393653320333333
3333333333333333332133333
3333333333333333332133333
```

Comment: Nice just what i was looking for! Thank you for showing me this, I have seen it for Strings, but wasn't sure how to work it with integers.

Comment: @Loligans Glad to know it helped.